# About SQL Server networking

Tags: sql-server-2005

I would like to connect from client PC to SQL Server over the internet. I have installed SQL Server 2005. Can you guide me. I am new to this.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Is there any reason why you need to expose your SQL server to the internet rather than using a VPN? If you want to do this safely, it can be quite complicated, and as a result we can only give you overview steps.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutally *must* access your SQL server over the internet, here is the birds-eye-view of what you need to do:

1. Permit inbound SQL connections from remote computers inside the SQL server. This is disabled by default in SQL Server 2005.
2. Permit inbound SQL connections on your Windows firewall (Port 1433)
3. Expose your SQL Server to the internet. Most commonly this will involve setting up a Port Forwarding for Port 1433 through your edge device to your SQL Server.
4. Permit inbound SQL Connections through your edge firewall (Port 1433).
5. To do this properly, you should absolutally lock down your edge firewall to only permit SQL Traffic from a very, very small number of IP addresses (the public IP address of the client you are going to use to connect to the server). I have a honeypot SQL Server set up and it gets about 1,000 attempts *a day* from different chinese botnets trying to break into it. Not doing this step is asking for huge trouble.

For the specifics for #1, you will find [how to do that here](https://serverfault.com/questions/202190/configuring-sql-server-express-2005/203161#203161). For #2, how to do so depends on your operating system. For #3 - #5 we will be unable to help you here because it requires very specific knowledge of your network setup.